# A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ that maps a circle to a circle

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose f is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ that maps a circle to a circle. How do I prove that f is differentiable? Will the function still be differentiable if continuity is not assumed?

Comment: Any circle to any circle, or one particular circle?

Comment: @Randall Any circle.

Comment: Interesting.   Does it map any circle to a circle or any circle to itself?  Big difference.

Comment: Any circle to a circle.

Comment: If the function $f$ maps the set of points {$(x,y): x^2 + y^2 = r^2$} to the set of points {$(u,v): u^2 + v^2 = R^2$} in a one-to-one fashion, doesn't that mean that the domain of the function is 1-dimensional and can only have directional derivatives $d/dt f(c(t))$ where $c(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$?

Comment: Oh any circle to a circle: emphasis on the word any and my other comment goes away

Comment: How did you come across this problem?